# How to get object from an associated model?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using NodeJS, Express, SQL, and Sequelize. I have 2 models: Route and Transport. A route belongs to a transport, a transport has many routes. I want to get the transport associated with my route so that I can get its data, something like:

```
route.getTransport()
```

or

```
route.transport
```

So that I can do:

```
route.getTransport().getName()
```

or

```
 route.transport.name
```

So I get all routes from my database:

```
Route.findAll({
            where: {
                destination: "Whatever",
                origin: "Whatever"
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
```

I have seen that I can do it if I add the "include" inside the query like this:

```
Route.findAll({
            where: {
                destination,
                origin
            },
            include: [{
                model: db.transport,
                as: 'transport'
            }]
        })
```

**But if I don't I iterate through every route found and I cannot access my transport associated. Isn't there a way to do this without having to do add the "include"?**

My model file for Route:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Route = sequelize.define("route", {
        origin: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        },
        destination: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        },
        transportId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            required: true
        }
    });

    return Route; 
};
```

My model file for Transport:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Transport = sequelize.define("transport", {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        },
        type: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        },
        capacity: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }
    });

    return Transport;
};
```

My relationship section in index.js for my models:

```
db.transport.hasMany(db.route, { as: "routes" });
db.route.belongsTo(db.transport, {
    foreignKey: "transportId",
    as: "transport"
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need specific `transport` rows based on some of your route lines? You can do a `Transport.findOne()` based on your requirements. But if you have a lot of lines to get is better to do by `include` to reduce the number of selects and , consequently, the load.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Route.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "id",
    "origin",
    "destination",
    "transport.name",
    "transport.type"
 ],
 where: {
    destination,
    origin
 },
 include: [{
    model: db.transport,
    as: 'transport',
    attributes : []
 }],
 raw: true,
 subQuery: false
})
```

Hope it will help anyone.

Comment: This uses include, I asked for a way to do it without the include.